# HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish

I have a Java Client on Glassfish that has to consume a soap web service from a third party but I can't get around the error:

```
"error":    {
      "code": "ClientTransportException",
      "description": "HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
}
```

I have the third party certificates in the JVM keystore and cacert but still no luck.

This is the (summarised) ssl messaging:

```
Info:   Using SSLEngineImpl.
Info:   Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Info:   http-listener-2(5), READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 181
Info:   *** ClientHello, TLSv1
Info:   RandomCookie:
...
Info:   ***
Info:   %% Resuming [Session-5, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
Info:   *** ServerHello, TLSv1
Info:   RandomCookie:
Info:   bytes = {
Info:   10
Info:   ,
...
Info:   ,
Info:   218
Info:   }
Info:   Session ID:
Info:   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Info:   Compression Method: 0
Info:   Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Info:   ***
Info:   Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Info:   CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Info:   Client Nonce:
Info:   0000:
Info:   55
Info:   /
Info:   http-listener-2(5), WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81
Info:   http-listener-2(5), WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
Info:   *** Finished
Info:   verify_data:  {
Info:   95
Info:   ,
...
Info:   ,
Info:   7
Info:   }
Info:   ***
Info:   http-listener-2(5), WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
Info:   http-listener-2(2), READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
Info:   http-listener-2(2), READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
Info:   *** Finished
Info:   verify_data:  {
Info:   241
Info:   ,
...
Info:   ,
Info:   206
Info:   }
Info:   ***
Info:   Finalizer, called close()
Info:   Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Info:   Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Info:   http-listener-2(2), setSoTimeout(0) called
Info:   %% No cached client session
Info:   *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
Info:   RandomCookie:
Info:   GMT: 1431349301
Info:   bytes = {
Info:   98
Info:   ,
...
Info:   Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=*****]
Info:   ***
Info:   http-listener-2(2), WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 244
Info:   http-listener-2(2), READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 81
Info:   *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
Info:   RandomCookie:
Info:   GMT: 305071236
Info:   bytes = {
Info:   16
Info:   ,
...
Info:   ,
Info:   157
Info:   }
Info:   Session ID:
Info:   Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Info:   Compression Method: 0
Info:   Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Info:   ***
Info:   %% Initialized:  [Session-7, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
Info:   ** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Info:   http-listener-2(2), READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 2084
Info:   *** Certificate chain
<b>Info:   chain [0] = [</b>
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=*****, OU=*****, O=*****, L=*****, ST=*****, C=*****
Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
modulus: *****
public exponent: *****
Validity: [From: Tue Apr 30 11:50:28 BST 2013,
           To: Mon Dec 25 10:50:28 GMT 2017]
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=*****, CN=*****, OU=*****K, O=*****, L=*****,     ST=*****, C=*****
SerialNumber: [*****]
Certificate Extensions: 2
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
CA:false
PathLen: undefined
]
[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
DigitalSignature
Non_repudiation
Key_Encipherment
]
]
Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
Signature:
0000: 52 52 A2 33 8F 48 81 85   F9 CD 8E A8 90 1B D0 01  RR.3.H..........
0010: 3E 09 FF EC F5 23 E0 6F   77 2B 5E 20 B2 BC FF CE  >....#.ow+^ ....
...
00D0: 26 70 A9 5C 6D 80 9E 72   B0 F0 75 1D F3 E4 93 41  &p.\m..r..u....A
00E0: 6E 11 43 CB 6E 6D 1E C3   BB C7 A2 6F 65 A6 B6 58  n.C.nm.....oe..X
00F0: 53 98 4D CA 0A EC 18 6A   D4 80 BE 19 43 AD 7D F7  S.M....j....C...
]
**Info:   chain [1] = [**
[
Version: V3
Subject: EMAILADDRESS=*****, CN=*****, OU=*****, O=*****, L=*****,  ST=*****, C=*****
Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = *****
Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
modulus: *****
public exponent: *****
Validity: [From: Thu May 06 11:35:16 BST 2010,
           To: Sun May 03 11:35:16 BST 2020]
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=*****, CN=*****, OU=*****, O=*****, L=*****,      ST=*****, C=*****
SerialNumber: [*****]
Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: A0 C0 66 47 F2 E2 D7 6F   44 6F 3C E9 44 77 32 1B  ..fG...oDo<.Dw2.
0010: 00 3A B3 B6                                        .:..
]
]
[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
CA:true
PathLen:2147483647
]
[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: A0 C0 66 47 F2 E2 D7 6F   44 6F 3C E9 44 77 32 1B  ..fG...oDo<.Dw2.
0010: 00 3A B3 B6                                        .:..
Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
Signature:
0000: C0 FC 52 0F 9F 43 A4 64   B4 F2 61 79 50 37 90 28  ..R..C.d..ayP7.(
0010: 0B F7 ED 2E C8 28 01 66   25 AD DC E6 9D 3E 30 ED  .....(.f%....>0.
...
00E0: A6 19 A7 71 7A 55 BE 4F   54 FA 4E DE DE BF FD 29  ...qzU.OT.N....)
00F0: 12 29 D0 48 B8 BA BB CC   57 11 24 7A A4 F5 0B 03  .).H....W.$z....
]
Info:   ***
**Info:   %% Invalidated:  [Session-7, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]**
Info:   http-listener-2(2)
Info:   , SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:
Info:   fatal,
**Info:   description = certificate_unknown**
Info:   http-listener-2(2), WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Info:   http-listener-2(2), called closeSocket()
**Info:   http-listener-2(2), handling exception:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**
Info:   http-listener-2(2), called close()
Info:   http-listener-2(2), called closeInternal(true)
Info:   http-listener-2(2), WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 637
Info:   http-listener-2(2), WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 1
Info:   http-listener-2(2), WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 4
```

Am  I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working.
I had to explicitly tell Glassfish about the cacerts to be used even with those certificates being available in the /jdk/jr, /jre and the glassfish domain config cacerts...

```
asadmin> create-jvm-options -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/security/cacerts"
```